# Best way for all instances of a Rendered Object to maintain a pointer/reference to shared textures/resources

Tags: c++, oop, sdl

I'm working in C++ on a small engine/game in SDL and Im trying to find the best way to organize and maintain the textures/resources that all the objects will use.

I've got a simple base class called RenderedObject which anything that is shown on screen inherits from. Any rendered object is going to have multiple textures and SDL_surfaces associated with it that it will piece together to render.

(for example, a character object which inherits from RenderedObject might have surfaces/textures for legs, body and head)

Different children of RenderedObject will have different textures associated with each class.

Since there will be multiple instances of these classes, obviously I only I only need to load/maintain one copy of their textures and then every instance can have a pointer back to that.

Im wondering which way would be better to do it:

1) Ive got a graphic manager which does all the image loading and rendering, so I was thinking I could use that to keep an array of all the textures for each object. But I'm not really sure how to link back to it from each RenderedObject instance.

Ideally Id like to just give each instance a pointer, and then be able to call something like the following in the constructor or something:

```
this->textures = graphicManager.getTextures(this);
```

and then the graphicManager could return some kind of Texture object containing all the textures for that object.

If I do it this way, Im not sure how Id make it so I can pass the object pointer in directly and have the graphicManager send back the right info instead of using some kind of enum or string which Id have to specify for each subclass of RenderedObject.

2) The other way I thought might work would be to just have all the textures be static members of the objects. I'm just not too familiar with using static variables. When would their values get initialized? Because SDL needs to be loaded/initialized before any texture loading can be done

Anyways, in conclusion Im really just looking for the best way to keep some kind of pointer or reference in each subclass of RenderedObject to its textures without having creating a bunch of enums or additional classes for each subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is as you said using a class to manage the graphics( I am too building a game engine, and chose this method for all external resources), however my approach would be different than yours:

When loading the given `RenderedObject` you would pass the filename or some other identifier of the needed graphics to the manager. The manager then would then check if that graphics is already loaded ( it keeps list of what is already loaded, preferably in a `std::map<std::string,SDL_Surface*>` ) and if it is already loaded, it would increase the reference count of the object ( you could use the refcount member of the SDL_Surface struct, or wrap it in another class ).

When the `RenderedObject` is freed, it would call the free function of the manager, which would decrement the reference count of the object. If the reference count reaches zero, the object can be freed. This way multiple `RenderedObject` classes can use the same `SDL_Surface` instance.

Comment: This method is what I usually use for my SDL demos and it works very well and is easy to extend to other types of resources